# Javascript Mongoose - hot to close properly after save

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I like to save a data to my mongodb using mongoose.
But somehow my connection is always closed before I can save my data.

Even `.this` seems to be ignored.
Already tried very crude (most likely nonsense) async await combinations.

Just in case you wonder, I verified my connection on some other place in code.

```
 let filesInFolder = await fileHandler.read(dir); // array of objects
 // map over files - create mongoose Object for each entry - save each to db - once finished close connection
 // for simplicity I just use one element here
 var measurementObject = new measurementModel({
   _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
   Ano: filesInFolder[0].ANO,
   DES: filesInFolder[0].DES,
   LSL: filesInFolder[0].LSL
 });
 measurementObject.save()
   .then(mongoose.connection.close())
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

`mongoose.connection.close()` close the connection immediately

what you want is

`.then(()=>mongoose.connection.close())`

---

example

```js
Promise.resolve()
   .then(console.log(1))

console.log(2)

Promise.resolve()
   .then(()=>console.log(4))

console.log(3)
```

Comment: For my understanding of javascript both lines should do the same. Whats the difference. I tried it btw and doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @FuzzyTemper `()=>mongoose.connection.close()` create a function, which is executed by `then` when the Promise finish. `mongoose.connection.close()` just do it immediately.

Comment: Allright so I got partial success. When I put that ``()=>mongoose.connection.close()``in one line with the ``.save()`` part. Than it works. But what I want to do: I want to close the connection at the total end of the application and await all operations to be finished before closing but that is not working.

Comment: @FuzzyTemper you can create a collection of all Promise and use `Promise.all()` to check all the things are done. I doubt you don't really need to close the connection, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, problem is: If I dont close the connection my node app will not stop, because it is maintaining the connection to db. So the app is just waiting for eternity.